# How does Byte stream reads 2bytes UNICODE characters

Tags: java

I have few characters in notepad that takes 2 or 3 bytes. I am able to use inputstream and output stream to copy the files. Bytes stream is for ASCII characters and Character streams should be used for UNICODE characters. How does input stream process 2 or 3 bytes characters?

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("E:\\Users\\17496382.WUDIP\\Desktop\\qwert.txt");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("E:\\Users\\17496382.WUDIP\\Desktop\\qwert1.txt");
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int len;
while((len = fis.read()) != -1){   //do this until int len is not -1
System.out.println((char)len);
fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
```

Comment: Talk to somebody who told you that. In fact, byte stream used for anything. It does not try to decode bytes into characters. InputReader does and it allows you specify the encoding, not limited to Unicode. Also, I recommend using try-finally to close the streams.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't. `InputStreams` read bytes and `Readers` read characters.

Your code will display garbage if it encounters a multibyte char. It may display garbage otherwise too, since you're assuming that `byte = char` (while that would work in many encodings).

Lastly: [Joel Spolsky's excellent article on Unicode](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html). Read it and you'll be smarter than a lot of other developers.

Comment: I agree that it shows garbage for 2 bytes characters on screen, but in the output file , all characters are stored properly. tried with 4byte, in the output file results are fine...

Comment: Well if you're just transferring all the bytes from one place to another, it doesn't really matter. However if you attempt to process the contents in some way (such as display them), you can't work with bytes any more.

Comment: Ok, tx for the clarification

Comment: If you want to understand completely, I suggest you read the link.